# Would this be a correct way to use the Repository pattern in ASP .NET MVC application implementing Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

This ASP .NET MVC application implements Entity Framework.

I've declared the repositories in the DbContext like this:

```
public class CompanyDbContext : DbContext
{
        // constructor goes here

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }

        private IGeneralEntityRepository<Customer> customersRepository;
        private IGeneralEntityRepository<Order> ordersRepository;

        // ...................
}
```

This way we can declare and initialise CompanyDbContext within a controller and then access the repositories using the CompanyDbContext instance.

Is this correct? Or should I create a separate "Unit Of Work" class to access the repositories?

Comment: This is the way EF5 builds out your code. And the controller builder puts `private CompanyDbContext db = new CompanyDbContext();` this in each controller it builds.

Comment: I understand that this is the way that EF implements the repository pattern. My question is, is this the right way to merge my own repositories with the EF repository? Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at this link http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repositories need to depend on the `DbContext` and not vice versa. Also, you don't have to implement Unit of Work since the `DbContext` already implements it. You could do it like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T ReadOne(object key);

    // so on, so forth...
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public T ReadOne(object key)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(key);
    }
}
```

This way, you keep your context clean and only need to worry about adding new entity configurations to it, when it is needed. If you use EF6 there's a method called [AddFromAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.configurationregistrar.addfromassembly%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) which allows you to add the configurations from an assembly. This saves you from modifying the `DbContext` each time you add a new entity.

I'd suggest looking into a DI container as it will greatly simplify the work required to put things together. You can sort out your DAL configuration with 2 or 3 lines of code.